# JPA products DB model design

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, database-design, jpa, jpa-2.0

I need to create a products DB. My products will have common attributes, such as price, description, brand... and specific ones, depending on their *category* (notebooks will have display size, ram, cpu and so on).

My generic entity is:

```
@Entity
@Table( name="products" )
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(
    name="discriminator",
    discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING
)
@DiscriminatorValue(value="GEN")
public class Product implements Serializable { 
   // ...
}
```

and here's an example of specific entities:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("NB")
public class Notebook extends Product {
   // ...
}
```

I want to query my Product entity for showing a table-list of all products in my DB.

I also want a "type of product" column to be shown.

How can I determine the subtype of the Product? Wheter if it's a notebook, a telephone or other kind of product?

There's a discriminator column, automatically created and managed by jpa, but what's the right way for reverse getting the *Product*'s type?

**If this is not possible, how can I re-design my model to achieve my goal?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map your discriminator column as a property at the same time (without being editable). So `Product` will have another property:

```
...
@DiscriminatorColumn(
  name="discriminator",
  discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING
)
@DiscriminatorValue(value="GEN")
public class Product implements Serializable { 

  @Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)
  public String discriminator;
  ...
}
```

When you execute a query for `Product`s, the result set will also contain `Notebook`s.

Comment: thank you. Is that a good design for a products model? How else can I do to be smarter? :)

Comment: You may want to rethink the inheritance strategy. With `SINGLE_TABLE` strategy all entities will be persisted in a single table, which will contain lots of columns with `NULL`s in your case. You may want to switch to `JOINED` strategy, but this has its cons too. Take a look at here for details: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance

Comment: And I think this deserves to be asked in another question :)

Comment: I already know about inheritance strategies. I mean... in this case it doesn't matter whether I am using one strategy or the other. I'd always have the same kind of problem. Your answer is good, but imagine that: I am displaying the "Product" query in a jsf datatable. Yes... I can display the discriminator column, but if I wanted to determine exactly what CLASS it is instance of... how would I do it?

Comment: I don't know JSF, so i cannot answer how to do that. But you can always use `instanceof` operator and check for each class in the hierarchy. Depends on the specific details i guess. That's why i suggested you open another question with more details.